# Do sum in a nested list of a given list

Tags: python, list

Than I want to write a function that achieves this purpose, if given:

```
t = [1,2,[2,2],[3,3]]
```

I want a function that makes t be 
`[1,2,4,6]`. Here, is my code in Python:

```
t=[1,2,[2,2],[3,3]]

def nested_sum(t):
    for x in t:
        if type(t[x])=='int':
            t[x]=t[x]
        else:
            t[x]=['sum(t[x])']
    return t

nested_sum(t)
```

I got the error message that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nested_sum.py", line 11, in <module>
    nested_sum(t)
  File "nested_sum.py", line 5, in nested_sum
    if type(t[x])=='int':
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

I am not quite sure about the mistake(s) I made. Since my logic is that:

`type(t[0])=1` which is of "Int" type and `type(t[2])=[2,2]` which is of "List" type and I think these fulfills the "if...else..." statement.

Any help would be appreciated for pointing my mistakes. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: `for x in t` binds `x` to each *item* in the list, not each *index*.

Comment: thanks jonrsharpe, I spot my error now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are looping through the items of your list and not through the indexes. For making it work you should change your code like this:

```
def nested_sum(t):
    for x in range(len(t)):
        if type(t[x]) == int:
            t[x] = t[x]
        else:
            t[x] = sum(t[x])
    return t
```

Note also that `int` in `type(t[x]) == int` and `sum(t[x])` in your else clause should not be strings.

Comment: Thanks Railslide, the simple change at the for-condition can make the program run.

Answer (score 4):

You can put it in a single list comprehension using isinstance:

`[sum(x) if isinstance(x,list) else x for x in t]`

```
[1, 2, 4, 6]
```

You could use collection.Iterable which will work on any iterable like tuples etc..

```
t = [1,2,[2,2],[3,3],(4,5)]

from collections import Iterable

print [sum(x) if isinstance(x, Iterable) else x for x in t]

[1, 2, 4, 6, 9]
```

In the list comprehension, if x is an iterable/list we add the `sum` of the subelements or `else` we just take the element `x`

Using your own code, you would use enumerate to access the list elements using their index:

```
def nested_sum(t):
    for ind, x in enumerate(t):
        if type(t[ind])== int: # int not "int"
            t[ind] = x
        else:
            t[ind] = sum(t[ind])
    return t
```

In the code `ind` is the index of each  subelement and `x` is the actual subelement

Comment: @wim yes I agree, I was going to add that.

Comment: thanks Padraic for your detail explanation. Since I am reading "Think Python" Chapter 10 and your programming seems too advanced for me at my present stage. I will refer to your explanations later if I acquire more knowledge on Python. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use sum() when x is a list, append it to res otherwise

```
t=[1,2,[2,2],[3,3]]

def nested_sum(l):
    res = []
    for x in l:
        if type(x) == type([]):
            res.append(sum(x))
        elif type(x) == type(1):
            res.append(x)
    return res

nested_sum(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def nested_sum(t):
    for index, item in enumerate(t):
        if type(item) == list:
            t[index] = sum(item)
    return t
```

Explanation:

`enumerate(t)` returns (0, t[0]), (1, t[1]) etc.

Then, for each `item` in `t`, check if `item` is a `list`. If it is, replace it with the sum of all elements in that list. This is done in `t[index] = sum(item)`.

Comment: Thanks Saimadhav for your explanation on function enumerate=]

Answer (score 0):

An answer would be:

```
def nested_sum(mixed_list):
    res = list()
    for element in mixed_list:
        try:
            a = sum(element)
        except TypeError:
            a = element
        res.append(a)
    return res
```

Which works fine if the list contains numbers and lists of numbers.